# Visual Studio compiled artifacts: Store in TFS or in a Filesystem?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, tfs, filesystems, storage

I've experienced issues with database growth with the berkeley db while awfully using svn as a library repo.

Now we are evaluating TFS. which as a code repo some people could favor it or not, but it works, and it does what we need it to do fine.

We need to store somewhere the compiled build for auditing issues when going to several environments (QAs, Prods, etc) to ensure it's exactly the same file.

My boss says that we should store them in TFS because of the plus value of revision history ("and other stuff which TFS offers"). But I disagree, a Code Repo should be to store Code. And to store the builds we should use a Filesystem, because...

We'll be storing stuff which in some time from now will be deprecated and noone will use, while in a filesystem we could develop a batch process integrated with the tfs msbuild which could do a weekly cleaning or something.

Indexing, backuping and other stuff could very well be done by winServ2008 normatives...

But maybe you could tell me better, which is the optimal way?

Comment: Why do you need to store builds?  If you have the source in TFS, you can always rebuild any version/label you like.  I'm trying to understand the motivation for keeping a long term store of builds whether it's in Source Control or the filesystem.  Also you can configure TFS to keep X number of successful builds automatically.  Default is 10 I think.

Comment: Why? well a mix of reasons: we deploy the same build on several environments (dev-Sth, dev-Nth, dev-EU, QAs, labs, and so on). It would be nice not to rebuild it every time we go to a different env, if we know it is a candidate to be deployed everywhere.
Afterwards, maybe tagging or labeling is the best option, but it will be a hard work and responsability to open short minded audits who do checksums of the builds to define if its the same build or not. (And IMHO this enforces my idea of filesystem).

Comment: TFS Deployer is a product that can solve this issue for you.  You build once then change the quality of the build.  This then triggers a powershell script to deploy it to multiple locations.  We use this and have qualities called "Publish QA", "Publish Staging", "Publish Live".  Alternatively, I believe something like Octopus Deploy would solve this issue for you too.